# How to handle html shadow dom using selenium webdriver?

Tags: javascript, java, selenium

```
public WebElement expandShadowRootElement(WebElement element) {
    WebElement shadowRoot = (WebElement) ((JavascriptExecutor)driver)
        .executeScript("return arguments[0].shadowRoot", element);
    return shadowRoot;
}

WebElement root1= driver.findElement(By.xpath("(//div[@id='accordionSearch']//descendant::input[@class='form-control'])[1]"));
WebElement shadowRoot1=expandShadowRootElement(root1);
WebElement element= shadowRoot1.findElement(By.cssSelector("div[id=editing-view-port]/div"));
element.click();
```

This code is not working.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Please explain better the *not working* part. Also, post the html as text, not as image.

Comment: My requirement is to select the check box and second time need to skip if it is already selected but those element coming under shadow room which is not visible.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing similar problem recently and the only solution that worked for me was javascript.
This is the example of Java code that I used. It gets `<div id="details">` from the first element in Chrome's download page and saves it as WebElement.

```
WebElement details = (WebElement) ((JavascriptExecutor) driver).
executeScript("return document.querySelector('downloads-manager').
shadowRoot.querySelector('#downloads-list downloads-item').
shadowRoot.querySelector('#content #details')");
```

[image]